# Fine-tuning gitk encoding

Tags: git

I've created an annotated tag in gitk with the folowing message:

> Plots são mostrados na mesma janela.

But now gitk shows:

> Plots sÃ£o mostrados na mesma janela

How to correct the encoding?

Comment: That's likely a bug in gitk. Try looking at it with the command line tools; if the bug was in gitk's input then you may be able to edit and fix it with the command line tools, but if it's in the display you probably can't. Is your environment set up to use UTF-8 throughout? It's possible gitk is assuming an encoding internally that's mismatched with your environment.

Comment: In Git Bash: git tag -a shows "Plots são mostrados na mesma janela.", correctly. By "your environment" do you mean Windows? How can I check?

Answer (score 21):

Have you set up the git encoding correctly?

```
git config --global gui.encoding utf-8
```

Looks like you did not set it correctly.
If this is the case you can still update the messages and alter them.

Annotated tag is a "real" commit so using `git filter-branch` with the desired flag can update your commit message to the right encoding.

Another option is directly yo update the tag message with the new message once you set up the right encoding
`git tag <tag name> <tag name> -f -m "<new message>"`